# How can I get pixel size in millimetres using camera calibration with checkerboard images in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, pixel, camera-calibration

I am using camera calibration APP in Matlab to get the camera information
I am wondering if it is possible to get the size of the pixels in millimetres once we know the size of the checkerboard square (mine 27mm)

Comment: Typically the pixel pitch (read "size") is shown in the camera's datasheet, you can find it there. But yes, you should be able to get a rough approximation. The calibration should give you back the focal length back in `pixels`. By using the pin-hole camera model, and undistorting your checkerboard corners, you calculate the pixel pitch using simple trigonometry.

Comment: How? .. I need more details please