# How to calculate mm per pixel of an image at a certain distance using camera calibration matrix?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pixel, camera-calibration

I saw the answers here:

1. [How can I get pixel size in millimetres using camera calibration with checkerboard images in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292473/how-can-i-get-pixel-size-in-millimetres-using-camera-calibration-with-checkerboa)

but it wasn't answered.

I have a fixed camera and an object at a certain `x` distance from the camera. I place a checkerboard (per square `y` mm) at this distance `x` and calibrate the camera to get camera calibration matrix.  How can I use this matrix and known distance `x` to find mm per pixel for any image of the object placed at distance `x`?

As a follow up, the object size increases such that `x` decreases (distance between object surface and camera) to give `x'`, will we need to recalibrate the camera for that new distance or can we somehow accommodate `x'` to still get accurate mm per pixel?

Comment: It's not going to work without a reference object (with known size), or without at least two images from different camera positions.

Comment: @Rotem But checkerboard has a known size. We can use it's values right?

Comment: Yes, if you have the checkerboard in your image, you know the size in mm of the checkerboard, and the size in mm of other objects in the same distance as the checkerboard (simple scaling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given *distance* (of the reference object) and *focal length* (pixels) from the camera matrix, **yes** it's just a bit of math.

If you want to know the length of a millimeter at a distance of 5 meters, and your focal length is 1400 pixels, calculate

```
1400 pixels * (1 mm / 5 m) = 0.28 pixels
```

So at 5 meters, you have 0.28 pixels per millimeter.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide a link/source or reasoning as to why this works?

Comment: this directly derives from the geometry and matrix math, given two points in space of the desired distance away and from each other. here's how opencv defines the camera matrix: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#details

Comment: Thank you, Does that mean once I find the pixels per mm, it only works for calculating pixel size of an object at same distance. If my object size increases in volume such that distance `Z` i.e. 5 mm in your example becomes like 4.5 mm, then same pixel /mm won't work? So I have to now `Z` (object distance from sensor) for all objects?

Comment: correct, the factor only works for that distance. for tiny changes (distance from camera to object), it won't matter much.

Comment: Hi, I used the formula and everything and I have a followup question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835734/pixel-per-mm-calculation-of-an-image-using-camera-calibration-matrix-and-object Thank you.