# Pixel per mm calculation of an image using camera calibration matrix and object distance is not same as pixel dimension of object in MS Paint

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I want to calculate number of pixels per grid (i.e. pixels per 11 mm) of the checkerboard. I am doing this to validate that mm/pixel calculation I obtain using calibration matrix and formula (below) is same as what I will see when I open the image in MS Paint.

For the checkerboard image (1920x1080 resolution): 11 grid x 7 grid in size with each grid as 11x 11 mm, at a distance of 500 mm (picture below).

[image: Checkerboard Sample Image]

I compute a calibration matrix using code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pathlib
#from utils import *
import glob
from argparse import ArgumentParser

topview_image_path    = 'checkerboard_top\*.png'

camera_orientation = 'topview'

if camera_orientation == 'topview':
    image_path = topview_image_path 


def calibrate_chessboard(folder):
# Defining the dimensions of checkerboard
    CHECKERBOARD = (6,9)
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    # Creating vector to store vectors of 3D points for each checkerboard image
    objpoints = []
    # Creating vector to store vectors of 2D points for each checkerboard image
    imgpoints = [] 


    # Defining the world coordinates for 3D points
    objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0] * CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
    objp[0,:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0], 0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)
    prev_img_shape = None

    # Extracting path of individual image stored in a given directory
    print("image path:", image_path)
    images = glob.glob(image_path)
    
    #images = glob.glob(f'{folder}/*.png')
    # if len(images) == 0:
    #     images = glob.glob(f'{folder}/*.jpg')
    # print(images)
    for fname in images:
        img = cv2.imread(fname)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Find the chess board corners
        # If desired number of corners are found in the image then ret = true
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, CHECKERBOARD, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
        """
        If desired number of corner are detected,
        we refine the pixel coordinates and display 
        them on the images of checker board
        """
        if ret == True:
            objpoints.append(objp)
            # refining pixel coordinates for given 2d points.
            corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11),(-1,-1), criteria)
            
            imgpoints.append(corners2)

            # Draw and display the corners
            img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, CHECKERBOARD, corners2, ret)
        
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    h,w = img.shape[:2]

    """
    Performing camera calibration by 
    passing the value of known 3D points (objpoints)
    and corresponding pixel coordinates of the 
    detected corners (imgpoints)
    """
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

    return [ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--type', dest='type',type=str, default='topview',help='is the image topview or sideview?')
    parser.add_argument('--folder', dest='folder',type=str,  default='cal_images/checkerboard_topview',help='is the image topview or sideview?')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    WIDTH = 6
    HEIGHT = 9
    # Calibrate 
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = calibrate_chessboard(args.folder)
    print(mtx)
    print(dist)


    mtx_list = ["calibration matrix:\n", str(mtx), 
                "\ndistortion matrix:", str(dist)]
    txt_file = "matrix_" + camera_orientation +".txt"
    
    with open(txt_file, mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        myfile.write('\n'.join(mtx_list))
```

and get the calibration matrix as:

```
M = [[2.86276094e+03 0.00000000e+00 8.23315889e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 2.86846709e+03 5.80987675e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
```

This gives me the focal length (`f`) in pixel units (M[0][0]) i.e. 2862.

I then calculate size in pixels (`X_sizepx`) of the checkerboard grid 11 mm (`X_sizemm`)  object at distance `Z` (in my case 500mm) using formula:

```
X_sizepx = (f/Z) * X_sizemm
```

Substituting all the values: f = `2862`, Z =`500`, X_sizemm = `11`, I get 62.94. So as per opencv calibration and the formula, 11mm should `~63 pixels`.

I then open the checkerboard image in MS paint to see the pixel dimension of the square grid in pixels and it says `41 pixels` (image below).

This is a big difference if I were to use camera calibration matrix and the the formula. Is there something I am doing wrong?

[image: Image in MS Paint]

**Note**: `Z` can never be more than 530 mm if I were to assume that `Z` might be slightly off.

Comment: You want precision, but you are ignoring many intrinsic parameters without explaining why.
You should explain the reason of this.
(Did you get the same result when using the full camera model?)

In general, there is no guarantee that the value of `f` will match the actual scale.
You can only think of any such unit for `f` if you give the initial `f` value (and if the result remains about the same value).
In calibration, some parameters are usually "fixed" to limit the degree of freedom of scale between the polynomial coefficients and the `f`.