# Is there already a camera/ pixel size calibration procedure?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using python and opencv for my project. For this project I need to measure the size of objects in the frame(objects are within one plane, lying on the ground. Camera is fixed in position). I wonder if there is already a camera calibration procedure, that allows to accurately calculate pixel to mm conversions, so that I could take the size of my object in pixels and convert it to mm.

Update:
I have intrinsics already calculated and for the calibration procedure I was planning on using an A4 paper with some kind of 4 shapes printed on it(all shapes are the same). I could detect those shapes with contours, distance between those shapes is known. I could perform perspective transformation to correct for camera angle. I could then calculate centers of those 4 shapes and calculate distance between those centers, then calculate the pixel per mm. Is this kind of procedure reasonable? What shapes should I be using to never mix those up with other real world objects in the frame?

Comment: you can get a chessboard pattern and take many photos on that plane and also, why not, tilted. Then you can calculate a ratio of pixel to mm. Use that to get the conversion ratio

Comment: @TinoD I mean I could do it manually, but I need some kind of automatic procedure that would be capable of calculating pixels per mm automatically, without human intervention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate mm per pixel of an image at a certain distance using camera calibration matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788052/how-to-calculate-mm-per-pixel-of-an-image-at-a-certain-distance-using-camera-cal)

Comment: put a known size detectable object (like a QR code) on your plane. Pre-computed you will need the camera intrinsics and lens distortion. Then you can compute the perspective homgraphy which gives you the pixel to plane (for example in mm) transformation.

Comment: @TomBlums there's also a very nice description here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#details